# UK Income Tax Liability

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom

I have been out of the UK for the last 9 years and just returned and started a new job. My salary is 42,800.

I started work the first day of October, so will have only worked 6 months at the end of the tax year.

Can someone help me work out my liability/deductions per month?

Thanks.

Comment: No explanations from the downvoters?

Comment: Any attempt at calcs / research yourself? Does [this question/answer](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/8450/calculate-income-tax-amount-of-uk-salary?rq=1) give you the required info? Maybe combined with [this answer on another question](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/62544/28861)? Both of these were found using the "Related" list to the right, which would have been suggested when you were writing your question...

Comment: (NB The first link was from 2011. The rates change each year. But if you follow the link used in that question, you can find the current rates.)

Answer (score 4):

Use a tax calculator (there are lots online) and for 2016/2017 tax year put in half your annual income, as you will only work half the year.

That will still calculate your income tax liability correctly - it doesn't make any difference whether you earned £X in 6 months on a £2X annual salary, or £X in 12 months on an £X annual salary: your total annual income for that year is still £X.

Putting in £21400 as your annual gross pay into http://www.uktaxcalculators.co.uk/ (and making various assumptions about your age, marital status etc.) gives total income tax liability for the year as £2080.

National Insurance is a different matter as that is calculated weekly:
 - 12% of your weekly earnings between £155 and £827
 - 2% of your earnings above £827

Your weekly gross pay would be £823 (£42800 / 52). Putting this in to the same calculator as the weekly pay gives a weekly NI liability of £80.16; across 6 months (26 weeks) this would therefore be a £2084 NI liability for the year.

So, for 2016-2017 your net income would be £21400 - (£2080 + £2084) = £17236.

Please do visit the calculator yourself and check my assumptions as these figures may not be exact if you have other income, allowances I don't know about, etc.

Comment: Few people on £42800 are paid weekly, therefore monthly NI rates would be more likely to be applicable. Also, the OP asked for deductions *per month*, not total by the end of the year.